# how to fix RNSVGGroup error in react native expo app?

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react native and following the tutorial on youtube. After setup sanity for the backend app gave an error. This is the tutorial:- https://youtu.be/AkEnidfZnCU

**this is my code:**

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import React, { useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, TextInput, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { UserIcon, ChevronDownIcon, MagnifyingGlassIcon, AdjustmentsHorizontalIcon } from "react-native-heroicons/outline";
import Categories from '../components/Categories';
import FeaturedRow from '../components/FeaturedRow';
import client from '../sanity';

const HomeScreen = () => {

    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const [featuredCategories, setFaaturedCategories] = useState([]);

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        navigation.setOptions({
            headerShown: false,
        })
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        client.fetch(`
        *[_type =="featured"]{
            ...,
            restaurants[]->{
              ...,
              dishes[]->
            }
          }
        `).then(data => {
            setFaaturedCategories(data);
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <SafeAreaView className="bg-white pt-5">
            {/* Header */}
            <View className="flex-row pb-3 items-center mx-4 space-x-2">
                <Image
                    source={{
                        uri: 'https://links.papareact.com/wru',
                    }}
                    className="h-7 w-7 bg-gray-300 p-4 rounded-full"
                />
                <View className="flex-1">
                    <Text className="font-bold text-gray-400 text-xs">Deliver Now!</Text>
                    <Text className="font-bold text-xl">Current Location
                        <ChevronDownIcon size={20} color="#00CCBB" />
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <UserIcon size={35} color="#00CCBB" />
            </View>
            {/* Search box */}
            <View className="flex-row items-center space-x-2 pb-2 mx-4">
                <View className="flex-row flex-1 space-x-2 bg-gray-200 p-3">
                    <MagnifyingGlassIcon size={20} color="gray" />
                    <TextInput placeholder='Restaurant and cuisines' keyboardType='default' />
                </View>
                <AdjustmentsHorizontalIcon color="#00CCBB" />
            </View>
            {/* Body */}
            <ScrollView className="bg-gray-100" contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 100 }}>
                {/* Categories */}
                <Categories />

                {/* Featured Rows */}
                <FeaturedRow
                    id="123"
                    title="Featured"
                    description="paid placemnts from our partners"
                />
                {/* Tasty Discount */}
                <FeaturedRow
                    id="1234"
                    title="Tasty Discount"
                    description="Everyone's been enjoying these juicy Discount"
                />
                {/* Offers near you */}
                <FeaturedRow
                    id="12345"
                    title="Offers near you"
                    description="Why not support your local restaurant tonight!"
                />

            </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

I have followed all the steps from the video. But it gives me an error.

**This is sanity.js file**

```
import sanityClient from '@sanity/client'
import imageUrlBuilder from '@sanity/image-url'

const client = sanityClient({
    projectId: "gbg977pk",
    dataset: "production",
    useCdn: true,
    apiVersion: "2021-10-21",
});

const builder = imageUrlBuilder(client);
export const urlFor = (source) => builder.image(source);

export default client;
```

**This is the error**
[image: Error img]

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In React Native, you should use the style attribute to apply CSS styles to your elements, rather than the className attribute.

Consider for example, the line:

`<SafeAreaView className="bg-white pt-5">`

It should be changed to:

`<SafeAreaView style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', paddingTop: 5 }}>`

Your code with the changes applied:

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import React, { useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, TextInput, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { UserIcon, ChevronDownIcon, MagnifyingGlassIcon, AdjustmentsHorizontalIcon } from "react-native-heroicons/outline";
import Categories from '../components/Categories';
import FeaturedRow from '../components/FeaturedRow';
import client from '../sanity';

const HomeScreen = () => {

    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const [featuredCategories, setFaaturedCategories] = useState([]);

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        navigation.setOptions({
            headerShown: false,
        })
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        client.fetch(`
        *[_type =="featured"]{
            ...,
            restaurants[]->{
              ...,
              dishes[]->
            }
          }
        `).then(data => {
            setFaaturedCategories(data);
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', paddingTop: 5 }}>
            {/* Header */}
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', paddingBottom: 3, marginHorizontal: 4, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                <Image
                    source={{
                        uri: 'https://links.papareact.com/wru',
                    }}
                    style={{ height: 7, width: 7, backgroundColor: 'gray-300', padding: 4, borderRadius: 'full' }}
                />
                <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'gray-400', fontSize: 'xs' }}>Deliver Now!</Text>
                    <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 'xl' }}>Current Location
                        <ChevronDownIcon size={20} color="#00CCBB" />
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <UserIcon size={35} color="#00CCBB" />
            </View>
            {/* Search box */}
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-between', paddingBottom: 2, marginHorizontal: 4 }}>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1, justifyContent: 'space-between', backgroundColor: 'gray-200', padding: 3 }}>
                    <MagnifyingGlassIcon size={20} color="gray" />
                    <TextInput placeholder='Restaurant and cuisines' keyboardType='default' />
                </View>
                <AdjustmentsHorizontalIcon color="#00CCBB" />
            </View>
            {/* Body */}
            <ScrollView style={{ backgroundColor: 'gray-100' }} contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 100 }}>
                {/* Categories */}
                <Categories />

                {/* Featured Rows */}
                <FeaturedRow
                    id="123"
                    title="Featured"
                    description="paid placemnts from our partners"
                />
                {/* Tasty Discount */}
                <FeaturedRow
                    id="1234"
                    title="Tasty Discount"
                    description="Everyone's been enjoying these juicy Discount"
                />
                {/* Offers near you */}
                <FeaturedRow
                    id="12345"
                    title="Offers near you"
                    description="Why not support your local restaurant tonight!"
                />

            </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

export default HomeScreen;
```